# Differential equation: $t^2x''+tx'+(t^2-3)x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

We have the following differential equation:

$$ t^2x''+tx'+(t^2-3)x=0$$

1. Give the set of solutions of the differential equation
2. What solution $x=x(t)$ check that $$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{x(t)}{t^{\sqrt{3}}}=0$$
3. What solution $x=x(t)$ check that $$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \ x(t)=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \ x'(t)=1$$
4. Find the solutiton which can extend analytically

---

I don't know how I could solve this problem, in fisrt, I thought calculate the series solution and work with it, but this is what ask us in paragraph 4, so 1., 2., 3. could do with out the solution, some one could help me with this problem? hint? thank

Comment: Look at standard textbook about [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first kind. In particular $J_{\pm\sqrt{3}}(t)$.

Comment: Assuming you have not yet studied Bessel ... Yes, use series; Do 1,2,3.  After that you will see that only one solution extends analytically.

Comment: the solution containes the Bessel-functiomn